# Register NPAPI Plugin from withing an SVG

Tags: html, plugins, svg, npapi

I Have been recently working with NPAPI Plugins for Chrome. The plugin has been implemented to be scriptable. I have a custom MIME Type for invoking this plugin.

In an html file, I have used an embed tag with the 'type' attribute specifying the custom MIMEType.
This works well and I am able to register my plugin and access the functionality.

If I choose to use a pure SVG file with no HTML content, how would I register my plugin?

Answer (score 1):

NPAPI plugins aren't part of SVG; why would you be able to use them from SVG? If you want to use something designed to be hosted in an HTML page you should use HTML.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was going to say as well. (lest you think a single opinion may not be correct)